# Delete non-zero rows in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have used the following code in MATLAB to delete the zero rows,

```
zero_rows = A(all(A,2),:);
```

I would like to know how to delete the non-zero rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the not sign `~` or use `any`

```
non_zero_rows = A(~all(A,2),:);
```

or

```
zero_rows = A(any(A,2),:);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your assistance. Have a nice day.